# Перевод из троичной С.С. в пятиричную, минуя преобразование в десятичную

Tags: c#, системы-счисления

У меня, как мне кажется, получилось реализовать таблицы сложения/умножения для пятиричной С.С., но совершенно не понятно как заставить их нормально работать для правильного преобразования.

```cs
    static int[][] additionTable = {
        new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
        new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 0},
        new int[] {2, 3, 4, 0, 1},
        new int[] {3, 4, 0, 1, 2},
        new int[] {4, 0, 1, 2, 3}
    };

    static int[][] multiplicationTable = {
        new int[] {0, 0, 0, 0, 0},
        new int[] {0, 1, 2, 3, 4},
        new int[] {0, 2, 4, 1, 3},
        new int[] {0, 3, 1, 4, 2},
        new int[] {0, 4, 3, 2, 1}
    };
```

Заранее спасибо!

p.s.
Добавил код, которым пытался реализовать алгоритм

```cs
static string ConvertBase3ToBase5(string base3Number)
    {
        string base5Number = "0"; 

        foreach (char digit in base3Number)
        {
            int base3Digit = int.Parse(digit.ToString());
            int Base5Digit = int.Parse(base5Number[base5Number.Length - 1].ToString());
            int sum = additionTable[Base5Digit][base3Digit];
            base5Number += sum.ToString();
        }

        // Удалить ведущий ноль, если есть
        if (base5Number.Length > 1 && base5Number[0] == '0')
        {
            base5Number = base5Number.Substring(1);
        }

        return base5Number;
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Write("Введите число в системе счисления 3: ");
        string base3Number = Console.ReadLine();

        string base5Number = ConvertBase3ToBase5(base3Number);

        Console.WriteLine($"Число в системе счисления 5: {base5Number}");
    }
```

Comment: Что именно непонятно? Что пытались сделать? Покажите код. При чем здесь сложение и умножение, если надо сменить систему счисления? Даже неясно, как именно у вас числа представлены. Непонятно, зачем эти таблицы, если все вопросы решаются математически.

Comment: @aepot Непонятно, как их использовать толком. То есть, я должен использовать эти таблицы, чтобы именно считать в пятиричной системе. То есть, если переводить число 212 из троичной в пятиричную таким способом, какой мне нужен, то это будет выглядеть так: 2 * 3^2 + 1 * 3^1 + 2 * 3^0 = 2*3*3 + 1*3 + 2*1 = 33 + 3 + 2 = 43 (все числа в пятиричной).
По заданию никакой промежуточной конвертации в десятичную С.С. быть не должно. 
А кода нет, я лишь только понял алгоритм, а как именно перенести его - нет

Comment: Какой тип будет представлять число?

Comment: @aepot, таблицы нужны если по условию задачи запрещено использовать арифметику на встроенных целых числах. То есть нельзя складывать, умножать и сравнивать целые числа. Тогда без таблиц не обойтись.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Ну, в моих попытках реализовать алгоритм я вообще делал число через string, который разбивал на массив char и работал с каждым символом в цикле. Особо ничего не получилось.

Comment: Раз `string`, у вас таблицы неправильные. Должны быть без целых индексов и значений, только на символах. Ещё таблицы вы дали по модулю, а должны быть полные. Ещё нужна третья таблица, которая устанавливает порядок на цифрах.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy А, нет, я немного ошибся. Массив из char я делал, но при каждой итерации цикла парсил в int.
Сейчас дополню вопрос тем куском кода, который хоть что-то, но делал

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а как вы цикл запустите, если складывать нельзя? Как вы к массиву обратитесь, если нельзя никак вычислить индексы?

Comment: @aepot, вычисления на строках (списках символов) пишутся на базовом Лиспе, где нет массивов. Если реализовать арифметику на массивах символов, то целые понадобятся только для индексации. Если реализовать арифметику на списках, то целые не будут нужны вообще. Я к тому что вычисления делаются на строках, обращаться к встроенному в язык целому не нужно. Решить задачу без целых - полезное упражнение.

Answer (score 1):

Число в пятиричной системе хранится как список цифр задом наперёд - первая цифра - младший разряд, последняя - старший. Вся арифметика, нужная для перевода системы счисления, реализована на этом списке.

Процедура `mul_add(n, f, t)` вычисляет *nf + t* - шаг схемы Горнера. Для цифр используется арифметика `int`, поэтому таблиц нет.

Число в троичной системе обрабатывается от старших разрядов к младшим. Результат накапливается в списке `n`. С каждым новым разрядом `n` умножается на три и к произведению добавляется очередная цифра: `mul_add(n, 3, d)`. Значение цифры вычисляется как разница символа-цифры и символа-нуля: `c - '0'`. Это ещё одно место, где используется арифметика.

Значение числа нигде не хранится в виде `int`. Программа преобразует числа любой длины. Арифметика используется в трёх местах: при вычислении следующей цифры и переноса, при преобразовании символа-цифры в значение цифры, при печати результата. От всех этих вычислений можно избавиться, но программа будет раз в пять больше, а принцип яснее не станет.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

const int Base = 5;  

// n = n * factor + term
void mul_add(List<int> n, int factor, int term) {
    int carry = term;
    for (int i = 0; i < n.Count; ++i) {
        int s = n[i] * factor + carry;
        n[i] = s % Base;
        carry = s / Base;
    }
    for (; carry != 0; carry /= Base) {
        n.Add(carry % Base);
    }
}

void main() {
    List<int> n = new List<int>(){0};
    foreach (var c in Console.ReadLine()) {
        mul_add(n, 3, c - '0');
    }
    for (int i = n.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        Console.Write(n[i]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

main();
```

Пример с числом Мерсенна *2<sup>89</sup> - 1*:

> ```
> $ csc convert.cs
> Microsoft (R) Visual C# Compiler version 3.9.0-6.21124.20 (db94f4cc)
> Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
>
> $ echo 101122101210001100022222220212111112120221202220200222111 | mono convert.exe
> 132231423444332013323140202444041441421
> ```